# Any plans to add a Win7-Style "Preview Pane" for previewing files in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

One feature I enjoy in Windows 7 is the Windows Explorer's Preview Pane. Will something similar be added to Nautilus for Ubuntu at some point in the future?

Comment: Do you have an image as an example before I show you my nautilus elementary?

Comment: do you mean the Goobus Preview?

Comment: Yeah. Gloobus is the/a new Elementary version. Nautilus is made so you can add your own scripts; I searched a bit but have not seen a script to add a preview for text files though.

Comment: any word on if a Preview Pane will be added to Ubuntu's default install of Nautilus so that the Preview Pane is just part of the file manager by default?

Comment: This question is too open ended, any answer will just be speculation.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to combine the Gloobus Preview interface with Nautilus i.e. so that you retain any new bug fixes for Nautilus through the repositories but also have the ability to preview files.

In summary, pressing the spacebar on a supported file (e.g. text, pdf, mp3 etc) in Nautilus will present a preview like this for a PDF:
[image]

and like this for a MP3:
[image]

If you want to try this suggest use the following packages:

Download and install Gloobus Preview from the PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/gloobus-preview)

Then download the Nautilus extension script from [here](https://github.com/DaKTaLeS/nautilus-gloobus-preview)

Install a small addition for nautilus

```
sudo apt-get install python-nautilus
```

Then extract the Nautilus extension script you have downloaded.

Install the script using

```
cd <folder containing the extracted extension script>
sudo python setup.py install --install-layout=deb
```

Logout and log back in.

Answer (score 2):

### Gloobus preview

Gloobus preview might be the tool you are looking for. I think it is the thing which is included in nautilus elementary, but it can be installed separatly too. For instructions on installation, look [here](http://gloobus.net/wiki/index.php?title=Install#Installing_Gloobus_Preview_from_the_PPA).

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus elementary does a preview of images like this:

[image: im1]

The [Gloobus project](http://gloobus.wordpress.com/) intends to have preview for all sorts of files but they are still developing I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try nautilus-elementary, now available on Natty:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/phew-nautilus-elementary-revived-in-time-for-ubuntu-natty/

Comment: sorry- I've just noticed someone beat me to it...

Comment: hey... it just shows we all agree on what is out there. I took a bit longer making a screenshot; doesn't mean your answer is any less good.

Comment: Will a Preview Pane be developed for the Nautilus installation that comes default with Ubuntu? Elementary is not the official file manager. You must install it via PPA?

Comment: Probably not... it'll most likely always be a PPA. Nautilus is sort of finished and if you want more you need to create your own script.

Comment: @Rinzwind and @Sam , see my answer - yes, such a script does exist.